# Displaying all objects in an array that match array values

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to web developing. I tried to figure the way to implement this out. This is my situation:

I have an array that contains object, and in that object, it contains an id for each of them. This is an example,

```
[ {id: 1, content: 'asdfadf', contentB: 'adsfasdf'}, {id: 2, content: 'asdfadf', contentB: 'adsfasdf'}, {id: 3, content: 'asdfadf', contentB: 'adsfasdf'}, {id: 4, content: 'asdfadf', contentB: 'adsfasdf'} ]
```

And I have the array that contains the ids of the objects that I want from above array. For example:

[1,4]

I'd like to display the objects according to the array values. What Javascript function should I use?

Thank you in advance!

Btw, my project now is currently using Vue.js, and the objects I'd like to display is actually on Vuex state.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var idsToFind = [1,4];
var data = [ {id: 1, content: 'asdfadf', contentB: 'adsfasdf'}, {id: 2, content: 'asdfadf', contentB: 'adsfasdf'}, {id: 3, content: 'asdfadf', contentB: 'adsfasdf'}, {id: 4, content: 'asdfadf', contentB: 'adsfasdf'} ];

var result = data.filter( item => idsToFind.includes(item.id) );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: or `idsToFind.includes(item.id)`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I do, but finding it takes longer than writing this answer. If SO improve the search, I'll be marking *even more duplicates than I already do!*

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks, I actually thought I wrote that. Well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

Create a better data structure, suitable for looking up by ID.

```js
var data = [ {id: 1, content: 'asdfadf', contentB: 'adsfasdf'}, {id: 2, content: 'asdfadf', contentB: 'adsfasdf'}, {id: 3, content: 'asdfadf', contentB: 'adsfasdf'}, {id: 4, content: 'asdfadf', contentB: 'adsfasdf'} ]
var map = new Map(data.map(o => [o.id, o]))

var ids = [1,4];
ids.forEach(id => console.log(map.get(id)))
```

This solution takes your data and converts it to a `Map` structure, where the `id` is the key that maps to the original object.

Then you can simply perform fetches on the `Map` using your list of IDs.

Comment: I won't downvote it because it works, but it's overkill. A `.filter` is much simpler.

Comment: @JeremyThille: Only if this is the *one* time the lookup will take place, which I would doubt. It should be seen as the preferred way to handle this when array items need to be looked up more than once by unique IDs within the objects in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce` function

```js
var targetIdx = [1, 4];
var data = [{
  id: 1,
  content: 'asdfadf',
  contentB: 'adsfasdf'
}, {
  id: 2,
  content: 'asdfadf',
  contentB: 'adsfasdf'
}, {
  id: 3,
  content: 'asdfadf',
  contentB: 'adsfasdf'
}, {
  id: 4,
  content: 'asdfadf',
  contentB: 'adsfasdf'
}];

var result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => 
  targetIdx.indexOf(curr.id) > -1 ? [...acc, curr] : acc
, []);

console.log(result);
```

## Resource

- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: Same as @SkinnyPete's answer : I won't downvote it because it works, but it's overkill. A `.filter` is much simpler.

Comment: @JeremyThille I totally agree with you, however, it's important to share another ways, that fills of knowledge our community and obviously to the OP.

Comment: That's a fair point.